# How can I get a reference to a label so I can change one of it's properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, label

I wrote this method to disable the autosize property of all labels whose name doesn't contain the string "Label".

```
private void DisableAutoSize()
    {
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (!control.Name.Contains("Label"))
            {
                (control as Label).AutoSize = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The line below is what causes the problem:

```
(control as Label).AutoSize = false;
```

The error I get says:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' (... as System.Windows.Forms.Label) returned null.

How can I access that AutoSize property?

Comment: **Hint:** Are they in the same container or in different containers?

Comment: ...if not, you have to say it, since this requires a recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

filter Controls by type and apply search condition using LINQ methods OfType() and Where():

```
private void DisableAutoSize()
{
    foreach (Label control in Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(c => !c.Name.Contains("Label")))
    {
         control.AutoSize = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What a great suggestion thanks, but the "OfType<Label>" part gives me an error saying "Queryable.OfType<TResult> is a method, which is not valid in the given context."

Comment: I forgot `()`, and it is supposed to be a method of Enumerable class, not Queryable

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all of the `Control`s in the form, at least one of which isn't a `Label`. Thus, the cast fails. In your loop, check for this condition:

```
private void DisableAutoSize()
{
  foreach (Control control in Controls)
  {
    Label label = control as Label;
    if (label == null || control.Name.Contains("Label"))
    {
      continue;
    }

   label.AutoSize = false;   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that `Controls` could contain non-Label controls as well. If you were cast a non-Label Control as Control (`control as Label`), it would return null. This is the reason you end up with `NullReferenceException`.

You can Filter Label Controls using [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) method. For example,

```
foreach (Label control in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
   if (!control.Name.Contains("Label"))
   {
      control.AutoSize = false;
   }
}
```

You can further expand the Linq to filter Labels based on the Name property using [`Enumerable.Where<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8), thus removing the if condition.

```
foreach (Label control in Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x=>!x.Name.Contains("Label")))
{
   control.AutoSize = false;
}
```